# Program to read data, split by delimiter, remove white spaces then count

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, collections, count

I have a program I'm working on where I need to read a .txt file which has multiple rows of data that look like this:

> [ABC/DEF//25GHI////JKLM//675//]

My program below can print each sequence on a new line for analysis, however the function is where I'm having issues. I can get it to remove the individual numerical values "675" and leave the alphanumeric ones. (Removes 675 from sample)

```
a = "string.txt"
file1 = open(a, "r")
with open(a, 'r') as file:
  lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file]
  print(*lines, sep = "\n")

cleaned_data = []
def split_lines(lines, delimiter, remove = '[0-9]+$'):
  for line in lines:
    tokens = line.split(delimiter)
    tokens = [re.sub(remove, "", token) for token in tokens]
    clean_list = list(filter(lambda e:e.strip(), tokens))
    cleaned_data.append(clean_list)
    print(clean_list) # Quick check if function works
split_lines(lines, "/")
```

This then prints out separated rows like this, removing the
white spaces (where "/" was, and numerical values)

> ["ABC", "DEF", "25GHI", "JKLM"]

What I'm trying to do is then use the "cleaned_data" list that contains these newly delimited rows, and quantify them to output this:

> 4x ["ABC", "DEF", "25GHI", "JKLM"]

What can I do next using "cleaned_data" to read each row and print a count of duplicate strings?

Comment: You have made *no* attempt to explain what properties of your file would result in this specific output.

Comment: Ah if I understand, the function returns the cleaned lines into individuals rows as they were before it was cleaned, the output just read those newly cleaned rows and counts them. I'm not sure what you mean by properties here.

Comment: You need regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pprint import pprint

unique_data = {}
cleaned_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 3, 4, 5, 'a', 'b', [1, 2,
                                                                       ],
                [1, 2, ]]
for item in cleaned_data:
    key = str(item) # convert mutable objects like list to immutable string.
    if not unique_data.get(key):  # key does not exist
        unique_data[key] = 1, item  # Add count of 1 and the data
    else:  # A duplicate has been encountered
        # Increment the count
        unique_data[key] = (unique_data[key][0] + 1), item

for k, v in unique_data.items():
    print(f"{v[0]}:{v[1]}")
```

Output:

```
1:1
1:2
2:3
2:4
2:5
2:a
2:b
1:c
1:d
2:[1, 2]
```

Comment: I've tried this, I'm very new to python so I think I'm misunderstanding. I'm getting an invalid syntax under count += 1 `unique_data = {}
count = 0
for item in cleaned_data:
  unique_data[item] = count += 1, item
  print(f'{count}:", {unique_data}')`

Comment: Try the revised solution and see if it makes things clearer.

Comment: Hmm I'm not getting an error for "unhashable list". The output I'm aiming for is similar to that, but the data that is counted should appear with each element sort of like: `1: [ABC, DEF, 65GHI] and so on. Sorry I might not be explaining as clearly as I could.

Comment: I have updated the answer to produce the format I understand you want. Let me know of any questions. You say you are new and I am glad to take the time to help you learn. Also, please accept the answer to confirm we have succeeded in working together.

Comment: I appreciate you do much @Carl_M. I am new and you've helped me understand how I need to structure this. Your instruction is exactly what I needed, and my program is spitting out exactly what I need from it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to get rid of duplicates:

```
    deduped_row_of_cleaned_data = list(set(row_of_cleaned_data))
```

If you need to know how many duplicates just subtract len(deduped_row_of_cleaned_data) from len(row_of_cleaned_data).

If you need a count of all duplicates you can create a list assigned empty dictionary from your deduped row:

```
    empty_dict=dict.from_keys(list(set(row_of_cleaned_data)),[])
```

Then loop through the list to add each value:

```
    for item in row_of_cleaned_data:
        empty_dict[item].append(item)
```

The loop through the dictionary to get the counts:

```
    for key, value in empty_dict.items():
        empty_dict[key] = len(value)
```

After that, you have the deduped data in

```
    list(empty_dict.keys())
```

and counts of each item in

```
    list(empty_dict.values()).
```